# How to use MariaDB's new "Invisible" column type

Tags: mariadb-10.3

I have been playing around with this new column type. The use case being that I want to hide this column from a client issuing a "Select *" query.

But the column seems to behave like any normal column and is not hidden. I have enabled the Invisible column type by using the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD COLUMN `TestA` INT INVISIBLE;
```

Reading up in the [MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/invisible-columns/), the examples provided are only with Create statements. Which makes me wonder if one can only enable this feature when creating a table and NOT with an Alter statement. Can anybody shed some light?

Answer (score 0):

The `INVISIBLE` is an attribute of the column it can be set CREATE TABLE and ALTER TABLE statements.

I've updated the [reference page document](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/invisible-columns/) to show this.

```
 CREATE TABLE t (x INT, y INT INVISIBLE, z INT INVISIBLE NOT NULL DEFAULT 4);

 DESC t;
```

```
Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra    
:---- | :------ | :--- | :-- | :------ | :--------
x     | int(11) | YES  |     | null    |          
y     | int(11) | YES  |     | null    | INVISIBLE
z     | int(11) | NO   |     | 4       | INVISIBLE
```

```
ALTER TABLE t MODIFY x INT INVISIBLE, MODIFY y INT, MODIFY z INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 4

DESC t
```

```
Field | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra    
:---- | :------ | :--- | :-- | :------ | :--------
x     | int(11) | YES  |     | null    | INVISIBLE
y     | int(11) | YES  |     | null    |          
z     | int(11) | NO   |     | 4       |
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=a3637a4dc60667480be05606cb5563e3)*